# Subsetting H2O DataFrame in R

Tags: r, h2o

I want to apply many distinct filters to an h2o dataframe to create unique subsets of data.  I also want to be conscious of the memory management process that h2o uses, because I will be applying this to gigabytes of data.

As far as I can tell from similar questions, there aren't many definitive answers for this topic, and most questions are more than a few years old.

```
library(h2o)    
h2o.init()    
h_mtcars <- as.h2o(mtcars)

### Subset of am == 1 and gear == 5 ###
index_am <- h_mtcars[["am"]] == 1
index_gear <- h_mtcars[["gear"]] == 5

index_combined <- index_am * index_gear 

h_mtcars[index_combined, ]
```

Is there any way to do this with a string, like we can with rlang and a dataframe?

```
library(rlang)

expressions <- "am == '1' & gear == '5'"

index_local <- expressions %>% rlang::parse_quosure() %>% rlang::eval_tidy(mtcars)

mtcars[index_local, ]
```

Comment: have you looked at the data manipulation section in the user guide: http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-munging/slicing-rows.html?

Comment: Thanks for the link.  It seems that the "boolean mask" approach is similar to what I have above, and it is very manual.  Ideally, I would pass a string to allow for a more programmatic complex subset creation.

Comment: Have you tried using data.table package? It allows this syntax and is faster for handling Big dstaset.